# Create a MinIO Bucket in NiFi - Using ExecuteScript processor and (J)python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, apache-nifi, minio

The 5 S3 related processor present in NiFi cannot create a Minio Bucket.

- ListS3
- PutS3Object
- DeleteS3Object
- FetchS3Object
- TagS3Object

So I tried to use the ExecuteScript processor and import the [python minio module](https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-api-reference.html) inside of it

In order to do that I install pip3 on my CentOS machine and did `pip3 install minio`(it installed it in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`).

Then in my ExecuteProcessor I set the following configuration :

**Script Engine** : python
**Script File** : No value set
**Script Body** :

```py
from minio import Minio
from minio.error import (ResponseError, BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou,
                         BucketAlreadyExists)

minioClient = Minio('minio',
                  access_key='XXXX',
                  secret_key='XXXX')
```

**Module Directory**: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/

But I keep getting this error

> No module named builtins in  at line number 1

Full error :

> ExecuteScript[id=3a3e689a-0170-1000-fa4d-b0874062b8cc] ExecuteScript[id=3a3e689a-0170-1000-fa4d-b0874062b8cc] failed to process due to javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named builtins in  at line number 1; rolling back session: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named builtins in  at line number 1

**Hypothesis 1** :

Of what I understand NiFi use Jython and then cannot use C-related Python module, I couldn't find the confirmation that minio-py was one of them but it seems to be the most relevant reason.

is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: switch to ExecuteStreamCommand processor to run your code as python (not jython)

Comment: Or even any other language, but with this method you cannot access the flowfile attribute or content